# Grouping Multiple Levels in a Query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, group-by

So this is what I have.
Have a function that returns loan exceptions.  So if someone has a missing document, that's an exception, or a signature required, that's an exception etc.
The problem is that ALL of the information being returned by this function contains all of the information for the loan.  Including the amount.
So if there are 6 exceptions on a single loan, and the loan is 1000, then totaling the amount by exceptions gives you 6000, because 1000 is stored in every record detail.
So here is a similar set of records that I am returning.

```
poolDesc| loanNumber| Exception  | Amount
Consumer| 123       | Missing Sig| 100
Consumer| 123       | Missing Doc| 100
Consumer| 123       | Late Pymt  | 100
Estate  | 456       | Address Ent| 2000
Estate  | 456       | Missing Doc| 2000
Estate  | 789       | Missing Sig| 1000
Consumer| 345       | Missing Sig| 500
```

What I am looking for out of that selection is:

```
POOL      CountExceptions LoanAmount
Consumer  4               600
Estate    3               3000
```

There has to be a way to do this, and its going to an SSRS report if that helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT poolDesc Pool,
       SUM(CountExceptions) CountExceptions,
       SUM(LoanAmount) LoanAmount
FROM (
    SELECT
        poolDesc ,
        COUNT(*) CountExceptions,
        SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY poolDesc, loanNumber ) LoanAmount
    FROM
        loanExceptions
    GROUP BY poolDesc, loanNumber, Amount
) a
GROUP BY poolDesc
```

full test script

```
create table loanExceptions (
    poolDesc varchar(50), 
    loanNumber int, 
    Exception varchar(50), 
    Amount float)

insert into loanExceptions values
('Consumer',123,'Missing Sig',100),
('Consumer',123,'Missing Doc',100),
('Consumer',123,'Late Pymt',100),
('Estate',456,'Address Ent',2000),
('Estate',456,'Missing Doc',2000),
('Estate',789,'Missing Sig',1000),
('Consumer',345,'Missing Sig',500)

SELECT poolDesc Pool,
       SUM(CountExceptions) CountExceptions,
       SUM(LoanAmount) LoanAmount
FROM (
    SELECT
        poolDesc ,
        COUNT(*) CountExceptions,
        SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY poolDesc, loanNumber ) LoanAmount
    FROM
        loanExceptions
    GROUP BY poolDesc, loanNumber, Amount
) a
GROUP BY poolDesc

DROP TABLE loanExceptions
```

Comment: script works whether some stalker of mine likes it or not  (blam)

Comment: You are correct.  This script worked very well for my needs.  Thank you very much.